# How to install plv8 in postgresql 9.5 on CentOS 6.7?

Tags: postgresql, centos, plv8

I installed PG 9.5 on CentOS 6.7 following this [link](http://tecadmin.net/install-postgresql-9-5-on-centos/comment-page-1/).

Then I downloaded `plv8-1.4.4.zip` from GitHub and followed instruction from these links: https://github.com/plv8/plv8 and http://pgxn.org/dist/plv8/ and README.
I did `make static` and it seems it build OK.
Now I'm blocked in next step

```
"Once you installed plv8 into your dabase, create language via
  $ psql -c 'CREATE EXTENSION plv8'"
```

How to install plv8 in DB?
Because `CREATE EXTENSION plv8` said that `plv8.control` file is not found.
If I copy manually `plv8.so`, `plv8.control` and `plv8-1.4.4.sql` in PG installation path - I receive error `symbol not found: oid_hash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found next installation how-to which helped me to install plv8 on my PG:

```
make PG_CONFIG=path_to_postgresql_installation/bin/pg_config
make PG_CONFIG=path_to_postgresql_installation/bin/pg_config install
```

[link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Building_and_Installing_PostgreSQL_Extension_Modules).